# Ubuntu is very slow on VM

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, ram, programming, motherboard

I recently upgraded my RAM from 4GB to 8GB on a 1TB Core i3 HP laptop. The assigned base memory of Motherboard on the VM is 4MB. I just found out that my Ubuntu is now slower than before. Could it be the upgrade? Do i have to increase the base memory? Please, what should i do?

Comment: You have a low end laptop with not a lot of RAM. The fact that you write 1TB indicates it does not have a SSD, and you don't mention the age or CPU of the laptop. It's going to be slow.

Comment: Other missing info is the version of Ubuntu being used. Is the VM Ubuntu is the Host Ubuntu? Unless this info is added to the question no good answer can be offered. Please edit the question and not answer in comments.